# while loop isn't working in my try/ catch statement

Tags: java, mysql

I have been trying to link this particular code to my database for a very long time with no progress. I am trying to make a fulfillment centre application that works for companies in this case like DHL and other shipping agencies, but I cannot link my code to the database I created with sqlite.

So I tried starting a new simple program and seeing if it works but I am getting an error in Eclipse when i initiate the `while(rs.next())` statement. Please help!

```
package test;

import java.sql.*;

public class db {

    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;

    public db() {
        connect();
    }

    /**
     * Database Connection.
     */
    public void connect() {

        try {
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);

            String db = "jdbc:odbc:db1";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
            st = con.createStatement();
            String sql = "Select * from Table1";
            rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

            While(rs.next()) {
                String fname = rs.getString("Fname");
                String lname = rs.getString("Lname");
                String age = rs.getString("Age");

                System.out.println(fname + " " + lname + " " + age);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // ignored
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new db();
    }

}
```

Comment: If your while loop doesn't enter then rs.next() returns false which indicates that there is no result.

Comment: `while` should be lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

It should be: -

```
while (rs.next()) {
 doSomething();
}
```

Br,
Rakesh

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there can be some `null` reference, so you cannot leave the `catch` clause empty, that will cause you won't know if there went wrong in the `try` clause.

So you print the stack trace:

```
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now if there happened some exception in the `try` clause due to `null` reference or some other exception, you can see the error by printing the stack trace.